# Substitute JSON Array Value Using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I’ve been trying for quite some time to get a JSON file and edit one of the values in the array (to be passed to PHP)

My current code is

```
j1 = $.getJSON("data.json") 
j1.responseJSON[name].job = "Carpenter"
```

When I use `console.log(j1)` after that, it logs the JSON the same as it was before (with name’s job being “Baker”). What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

**UPDATE 1: ADDED JSON**

```
{
     name:{
          {"job":"Baker", "age":"twenty-three","educated":"yes"}
     }
}
```

Comment: i think we need to see the json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$.getJSON("data.json")` is async. You need a callback. Otherwise you set the value before the request is being done.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function(j1){
    j1.responseJSON[name].job = "Carpenter"
    console.log(j1)
})
```